# Is there any way to run user uploaded pages securely on PHP?

Tags: php

I would like to upload files (php sites/applications) to given directory and run them there, within my web server. However, already a simple shell_exec call can cause serious consequences.

All the things I can think of are setting the pages directory outside the public_html and setting the permissions automatically so that the user running that page doesn't have any rights outside it.

Other mediocre solution I've found so far is [runkit_sandbox](https://www.php.net/runkit), which looks quite unsecure solution, specially as it seems to be abandoned.

Is there really no way? Not even with full shell access (shell scripts)?

Comment: This is a pretty bad idea if you don't trust the uploaders.

Comment: I don't understand very well, why do you need to let your users to run scripts on your servers? Or you want only to let them to deploy their php applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There are a virtually unlimited number of malicious behaviors that user-uploaded code can engage in, many of which closely resemble legitimate behavior (e.g, sending mail vs. sending spam; accessing external APIs vs. perpetrating a DDoS; running a command-line utility vs. running an exploit; managing files vs. deleting everything). There is generally no "canned" way to do this, and definitely none within PHP.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.suphp.org/Home.html

Answer (score 0):

Use open_basedir to restrict your users to a certain folder. In this way it can execute his files with his ownership, but it will not be able to see anything more than his folder.

Look here for more informations:

http://www.randombugs.com/php/apache-dynamic-virtual-hosting-php-security.html

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir